# how to create a dynamic hot spots using php?

Tags: php

i am stuck here please any one suggest me how to do this. i want like this http://www.finchatton.co.uk/. in this URL at top of the menu there is a link "COMPLETED DEVELOPMENTS". please click once. in this page click on one of the area in map.  now we will get hot spots in map. so i have to create that spots dynamically.

anybody give an idea.

thanks.

Comment: God I hate flash sites..

Answer (score 0):

That is done in Flash, it has nothing to do with PHP. PHP could probably be used to parse some data that Flash uses later...

EDIT: If you want the same functionality...

I suggest using Google maps API http://code.google.com/intl/lv/apis/maps/index.html
Just store the interest points in database with coords, then just fetch and display them on the google map.

Comment: no i am not doing flash site. it is just my reference page. actually how to develope that type of function using php/mysql.please suggest me